# How do I make a typing animation?

Tags: javascript, string, animation, settimeout, setinterval

I've been attempting to create a typing animation program that creates an animation of typing a word. Every period of time (1 second), it adds a letter to the output, seemingly "typing" the word out. Here is my code:

```
let input = document.querySelector("#input");
let text = document.querySelector("#text");
let run = document.querySelector("#run");
let str = input.value;

run.onclick = function() {
  text.innerText = "";
  str = input.value;
  let chars = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    chars[i] = str.charAt(i);
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      text.innerText += chars[i];
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO! There are lots of questions/answers about typewriting code on here. Please use the search bar to look at some of them.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one implementation using `setInterval`.

*As `Andy` mentioned in the comments, just search and you'll find plenty of other implementations and answers here at SO.*

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#input"); // Custom text to animate
const text  = document.querySelector("#text");  // Where animation is going to appear
const run   = document.querySelector("#run");   // Initiate the animation

run.addEventListener("click", function() {

  text.innerText = "";         // Clear the animation element before starting again
  const str = input.value;     // Get the custom text input value
  const chars = str.split(""); // Split the text string value and add it to an array: "123" => ["1","2","3"]
  const interval = setInterval(()=>{
    if ( !chars.length ){ 
      return clearInterval(interval); // Stop the animation once we're out of characters.
    }
    text.textContent += chars.shift(); // Remove the first character from the array and append it to the text display element
  }, 100 );

});
```

```html
<input id="input" value="Hello world" />
<p id="text"></p>

<button id="run">Run animation</button>
```